# SQL - select value that only match certain (multiple) unique conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following (example) table:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+---------+
| alarminc_no | cust_name  | event_id | site_no |
+-------------+------------+----------+---------+
|       99999 | Jonh Smith | UYALR    |    9090 |
|       99999 | Jonh Smith | UYBR     |    9090 |
|       99999 | Jonh Smith | PAF      |         |
|       77777 | Allan      | UYBIC    |    9090 |
|       77777 | Allan      | UYBR     |    9090 |
|       77777 | Allan      | PAF      |    9090 |
|       88888 | Susan      | UYGR     |    9090 |
|       88888 | Susan      | UYLAR    |    9090 |
|       88888 | Susan      | PAF      |    9090 |
+-------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

I need the alarminc_no that matches the following event_id's:

'PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM',
'UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED',
'UYPAN','UYTAM

There are MANY others event_ids, I need ONLY the alarminc_no numbers that contains these event_id's and not others.
Every Alarminc_no has multiple event_IDs, I need every one that contains at least ONE of these values, doesnt matter if contains another also, the rule is:

Every AlarmInc_no in the ouptut, should have in the event_id mandatory PAF, PFA and some of the events of the list (that events also are mandatory, at least one of them must be present), and can have also other events.

A user from this forum helped me with this code, but is working partially, it gives me a lot of the alarminc_no that I need but some are missing, and I dont know why.

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE 
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT alarminc_no, system_no
  FROM (
    SELECT alarminc_no,system_no,
       CASE WHEN event_id in
         ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM',
          'UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED',
          'UYPAN','UYTAM') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BAD,
       CASE WHEN event_id in ('PAF','PFA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GOOD
    FROM MYTABLE
    where event_date between '01/12/2016' and '31/12/2018'
  ) X
  GROUP BY alarminc_no, system_no
  HAVING SUM(BAD) = 0 AND SUM(GOOD) > 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1
) X ON MYTABLE.alarmic_no = X.alarmic_no AND MYTABLE.system_no = x.system_no
```

This is a screenshot of the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp3ax.png

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: If your first CASE statement is the list of 'good' event id's, don't call them 'bad'... call them 'GOOD'. Move that whole list down to the 'GOOD' case statement.  Then delete the first CASE statement. Then change your HAVING statement to: `HAVING SUM(GOOD) > 0`   

If that's doesn't give your your anticipated output, then you are not explaining your output constraints properly.

Comment: i, thank you for your time!. I need to get the alarminc_no that have PFA and PAF (always) and some of the other values of the list, buy ONLY these (there are MANY eventIDS, I need every alarmINC that has at least one reference to any of the values of the list). This script is working partially, for some reason it gives me part of the events I want, but are left others, I should clarify that every alarminc_no contains multiple eventIDs, and if an AlarmInc has a eventID wanted (UYALR for example) and another not wanted, I need it in the output anyway, cause UYALR is present.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the script should exclude the 'GOOD' part. The HAVING statement will only be true for alarminc_no's that have a record with event_id in ('PAF','PFA') AND a second record that has an event_id in in the larger group. If ('PAF','PFA') is not required, you can try the modified script below:

```html
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE 
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT alarminc_no, system_no
  FROM (
    SELECT alarminc_no,system_no,
       CASE WHEN event_id in
         ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM',
          'UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED',
          'UYPAN','UYTAM') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BAD--,
       --CASE WHEN event_id in ('PAF','PFA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GOOD
    FROM MYTABLE
    where event_date between '01/12/2016' and '31/12/2018'
  ) X
  GROUP BY alarminc_no, system_no
  HAVING SUM(BAD) = 0 /*AND SUM(GOOD) > 0*/ AND COUNT(*) > 1
) X ON MYTABLE.alarmic_no = X.alarmic_no AND MYTABLE.system_no = x.system_no
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time!.

I need to get the alarminc_no that have PFA and PAF (always) and some of the other values of the list, buy ONLY these (there are MANY eventIDS, I need every alarmINC that has at least one reference to any of the values of the list).

This script is working partially, for some reason it gives me part of the events I want, but are left others, I should clarify that every alarminc_no contains multiple eventIDs, and if an AlarmInc has a eventID wanted (UYALR for example) and another not wanted, I need it in the output anyway, cause UYALR is present.

Comment: Okay, can you replace the HAVING clause with the following and test it:   HAVING (SUM(BAD) = 0 OR SUM(GOOD) > 0) AND COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: Replacing the having clause as you say it gives me the following error: "name of the collumn "good" is not valid".

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Not sure you still need this. Ensure all column names in the HAVING clause are correct.

Answer (score 0):

To get records:

```
SELECT *
FROM @your_table t
WHERE t.event_id IN ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM','UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED','UYPAN','UYTAM')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @your_table tt
        WHERE t.alarmic_no = tt.alarmic_no
            AND tt.event_id NOT IN ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM','UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED','UYPAN','UYTAM')
        )
```

To get only alarminc_nos:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.alarminsc_no
FROM @your_table t
WHERE t.event_id IN ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM','UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED','UYPAN','UYTAM')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @your_table tt
        WHERE t.alarmic_no = tt.alarmic_no
            AND tt.event_id NOT IN ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM','UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED','UYPAN','UYTAM')
        )
```

Comment: Your code seems to work but, for some reason the output gives me all the alarminc_nos that have PAF and PFA but NOT the rest of the events, it listed me all the events with PFA and PAF excluding the ones I need.
This is the closest I got, its perfectly giving me all the records that have PAF, PFA but not the rest of the values I put above, and giving me the others, can you revert it? that would be the solution I think! and thank you so much for your time.

Comment: To clarification (sorry for my eng) see this:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7b8409a65886dd13e9e0519cfdbfd80